# Change CSS for each item in Rails each method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

So my each method works, but I am trying to add some code to make the dice change to its color that it is given. I am using rails and jquery/javascript. I just want to print the "dice type" and have it printed in the color it is given. Any thoughts?

Heres my original code:

```
                <% @last_move.rolls.last.results.each do |dice| %>
                  <li>
                    <%= dice.type %> - <%= dice.color %>
                  </li>
                <% end %>
```

And heres is my sorry failed attempt to make it just display the type with the color given:

```
                <% @last_move.rolls.last.results.each do |dice| %>
                  <li>
                   <script>
                     $(this).css({ color: "<%= dice.color %>" });
                   </script>
                    <%= dice.type %>
                  </li>
                <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use JavaScript for this, instead:

```
<% @last_move.rolls.last.results.each do |dice| %>
  <li class="dice-<%= dice.color %>">
    <%= dice.type %> - <%= dice.color %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Then in your css:

```
.dice-red {
    color: //red, etc.
}
```

Comment: This way you can give static color red to dice. but color should be that user enters in dice color.

Comment: How many colours do you need? If you only need 4 or 5 colours I'd do it that way. Otherwise output the colour using inline CSS <li style="color: <%= dice.color %>">.

Comment: Think I could just do  <li style="color: <%= dice.color %>;"> instead of messing with the css file. Thanks again :)